# Only temporarily disabling or powering off connected cameras

Tags: usb-device

I've seen many answered questions about permanently dis-configuring a webcam or any webcams at all to disable them permanently. This is not the case at hand.

Can one temporarily disable a v4l2 managed webcam or power it off using the v4l2-ctl command or otherwise, such that it no longer maps to a /dev/video* file handle and/or is no longer powered on, rather than physically plugging it out?

I am asking this for working with a plurality of connected USB cameras in a software development scenario, in which it is between helpful and highly enabling to be able to flexibly switch between sets of connected cameras, so answers like using black tape and such won't be relevant here ― I really mean how to disable (and later enable) connected webcams without physically unplugging them. If there's such a feature for USB webcam devices or any device at all ...

On systems using the standard v4l2 driver framework for USB/UVC cameras.

Comment: It's also helpful when you are testing webcams, being able to restart them without using your humanoid form factor for the physical interaction. Obviously niche.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on on USB ports, you might be able to disable (power down) the port, which would cause the camera to disconnect.

You could try using `uhubctl` to powerdown and powerup the port. This should cause the device to reset and that should kernel to redetect it.

eg on my machine this will turn off/on USB port 1-2.2

```
# /usr/sbin/uhubctl -l 1-2 -p 2 -a off  
Current status for hub 1-2 [0bda:5411 Generic 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub, USB 2.10, 4 ports]
  Port 2: 0101 power connect []
Sent power off request
New status for hub 1-2 [0bda:5411 Generic 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub, USB 2.10, 4 ports]
  Port 2: 0000 off

# uhubctl -l 1-2 -p 2 -a on 
Current status for hub 1-2 [0bda:5411 Generic 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub, USB 2.10, 4 ports]
  Port 2: 0000 off
Sent power on request
New status for hub 1-2 [0bda:5411 Generic 4-Port USB 2.0 Hub, USB 2.10, 4 ports]
  Port 2: 0101 power connect []
```

Not all USB ports can be controlled that way.

Working out the correct values for -l and -p can be a bit of trial and error; looking at `dmesg` output can help.

Comment: So just to directly tie this to v4l2 camera identifications ... how does one e.g. repower a camera addressed by the latter as: `usb-0000:00:14.0-2` ?

Comment: And should one understand that linux does not directly support powering (USB) devices on and off in a way obviating the need for libraries for it?

Comment: Not sure I understand that last comment; the uhubctl command tells the USB port to power down or power up.  You don't tell the equipment to turn on/off (most don't even know what that is) you tell the port it's connect to and that removes power to the device.  If you look at `dmesg` it should say something like `[#####.##] usb 1-2.2: Product: Your Camera`   The 1-2 is the hub (the -l value) and the 2 is the port (-p).

Comment: The last comment was a question about being able to accomplish the same without a library sitting farther outside the linux kernel like uhubctl.